# How to initialize a Google Map based on location?

Tags: api, google-maps, maps, location

So I am trying to initialize a google map based on a string location instead of latitude and longitude. Here's my current code

```
function initialize() {
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644); // Want to pass an address here
var myOptions = {
  zoom: 8,
  center: latlng,
  streetViewControl: false,
  mapTypeControl: false,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
    myOptions);
}
```

I looked up Geocoding. How would i initialize the lat long from an address like "Brooklyn, NY"

Answer (score 0):

You're already on the right track with Geocoding, read the following doc and ask any questions you still have, it's pretty straight forward once you get into it.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/